# Is $g(x) \in \mathrm{argmax}_{y \in \Omega} \, f(x,y)$ (Lipschitz) continuous when so is $f(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Let $D$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega$ be a *compact* subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$; $\;f: D \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define $M(x) \subseteq \Omega$ as 
\begin{equation}
   M(x) := \{ y \in \Omega: f(x,z) \leq f(x,y) \textrm{ for all } z \in \Omega \},
\end{equation}
*which can be considered as the "argmax" operator on $f$ over $\Omega$.*
Then, $M(x)$ is not empty since for every $x \in D$, $f(x, \cdot)$ has its maximum (and of course its minimum) over the *compact* set $\Omega$. Let $g: D \to \Omega$ be any function satisfying
\begin{equation}
   g(x) \in M(x).
\end{equation}
and suppose that $M(x)$ is a singleton for all $x \in D$, so that $g(x)$ is uniquely defined.
Then, my questions can be summarized as follows.

1. **(Continuity of $g(x)$)** Can we conclude that $g$ is continuous? If not, what's the additional condition(s) on $f$ (or its domain $D$) to hold continuity of $g$?
2. **(Lipschitz Continuity of $g(x)$)** Is $g$ is Lipschitz continuous when so is $f$?$-$here, Lipscthiz continuity on $f$ means that there is $L > 0$ such that \begin{equation}
   \big | \, f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2) \big | \leq L \, \big \|(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2) \big \| \;\;\;\,
   \forall (x_1, y_1), \, (x_2, y_2) \in D \times \Omega,
   \end{equation} 
   where $\| \cdot \|$ is any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$.
3. What happens if $M(x)$ is not a singleton, but contains at least two elements for some or all $x \in D$?

---

I think the statements do not hold in general, but I fail to give a counter-example or prove that it's true. I also found some discussions on the continuity of $h(x) := \max_{y \in \Omega} f(x,y)$, e.g.,

1. [Is supremum over a compact domain of separately continuous function continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450656/is-supremum-over-a-compact-domain-of-separately-continuous-function-continuous)
2. [How prove this $g(x)=\sup{\{f(x,y)|0\le y\le 1\}}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609012/how-prove-this-gx-sup-fx-y0-le-y-le-1-is-continuous-on-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Is $f(x)=\sup_{y\in K}g(x, y)$ a continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698150/is-fx-sup-y-in-kgx-y-a-continuous-function).

However, those cases do not discuss about the continuity of $g$ constructed by "argmax", rather than "sup" or "max."

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This $g$ might not even be well defined. What happens if $f \equiv 0$?

Comment: You're right. Now, I edited it to make $g$ well-defined, where $M(x)$ can be considered as the "argmax" operation.